# How to test a MySQL connection

Tags: 6, database

How can I test for active MySQL connections? I am trying to move one site to windows platform, and MySQL connections are failing; `db_query()` returns `FALSE`.
I am not sure how to use `drupal_test_mysqli()`.

Comment: $flag       = db_is_active(); tried this it returns true , but any db_query return s false , am sure query is correct in syntax

Comment: Did you open the logs? MySQL, Apache and PHP have almost certain explained quite detailed what your problem is, in the server logs. **Use the Logs, Luke**

Comment: have checked logs theres no error ,although in php.ini if set display_errors as on i get mysql server gone away while inserting into watchdog . i checked db_version() db_is_active() all returns true values, its not inserting or fetching records from db

Comment: i tried drupal_schema_fields_sql($table="zipcode",$prefix=NULL); i wont get any value for this . . .

Comment: @kantu: Does MySQL-log itself not show the errors? "MySQL has gone away" often indicates a crash of MySQL, which will be reported in the MySQL logs, often with details on why it crashes, or at least a code that allows you to google for an answer, or that you can paste here.

Comment: no error in logs ,checked mysql drupal apache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is invoked with code similar to:

```
$success = array();
$url = 'mysqli://username:password@localhost/databasename';

require_once './includes/install.mysqli.inc';
$err = drupal_test_mysqli($url, $success);
```

Replace `username`, `password`, `localhost`, and `databasename` with the values correct for your site.
The variable `$success` will contain an array with a value for each SQL instruction that has been executed with success.

Comment: i get call to undefined function drupal_test_mysqli()

Comment: I updated the answer: the function is defined in a file that is not automatically loaded by Drupal; it is used by Drupal only when it is being installed.

Comment: Isn't this a D6 function?

Comment: @ram4nd Yes, it is. It is the question that is using the wrong tags, since the OP is expressly asking how to use `drupal_test_mysqli()`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I just said it because of the wrong tag that seems to be fixed now.